# What is the meaning of "The number of units in the LSTM cell"?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, rnn

From Tensorflow code: [Tensorflow. RnnCell.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py)

```
num_units: int, The number of units in the LSTM cell.
```

I can't understand what this means. What are the units of LSTM cell? Input, Output and Forget gates? Does this mean "the number of units in the recurrent projection layer for Deep LSTM"? Then why is it called "number of units in the LSTM cell"?   What is an LSTM cell and how is it different from an LSTM block, what is the minimal LSTM unit if not a cell?

Comment: FYI [Understanding LSTM units vs. cells](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/241985/12359)

Comment: If the layer contains multiple parallel LSTM units, how it handles the input x? case 1: h(1) = f(x) h(t) = f(h(t-1),x) h(t+1) = f(h(t), x) case 2: h(1) = f(x) h(t) = h(t-1) Maybe there is other case like ResNet.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As the helpful comments in that function say,

> The definition of cell in this package differs from the definition used in the
>     literature. In the literature, cell refers to an object with a single scalar
>     output. The definition in this package refers to a horizontal array of such
>     units.

In essence, the layer will contain multiple parallel LSTM units, structurally identical but each eventually "learning to remember" some different thing.

Comment: Thanks :) That comment was added 7 days ago, after this question.  After some digging I have asked Tensorflow team in Google group why they definition of LSTM cell is differs from literature LSTM cell.. and they have added that comment :)

Answer (score 22):

Most LSTM/RNN diagrams just show the hidden cells but never the units of those cells. Hence, the confusion. 
Each hidden layer has hidden cells, as many as the number of time steps.
And further, each hidden cell is made up of multiple hidden units, like in the diagram below. Therefore, the dimensionality of a hidden layer matrix in RNN is (number of time steps, number of hidden units).

[image]

Comment: This is the clearest answer that I have seen so far!

Comment: Ok, but what about features? Isn't it `(number of time steps, number of features, number of hidden units)`?

Answer (score 3):

In Keras, which sits on top of either TensorFlow or Theano, when you call `model.add(LSTM(num_units))`, num_units is the dimensionality of the output space (from [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L602), line 863). To me, that means `num_units` is the number of hidden units whose activations get sent forward to the next time step.

Answer (score 1):

The number of units in a RNN is the number of RNN memory units to each input of the sequence in vertical manner attached to each other, and each one is passing the filtered information to next memory units.

Remember this concept was inspired from the computer science concept of the flow of memory allocation to different units the bit size.